# django - How to auto-populate existing data in django form while updating

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to auto populate my update form in django with the existing data, but `instance=request.user` and `instance=request.user.profile` seems not to be auto populating the form

views.py

```
def UserProfile(request, username):
    # user_profiles = Profile.objects.all()
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
    url_name = resolve(request.path).url_name

    context = {
        'profile':profile,
        'url_name':url_name,
    }

    return render(request, 'userauths/profile.html', context)





@login_required
def profile_update(request):
    info = Announcements.objects.filter(active=True)
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    user = request.user
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=user)

    if request.method == "POST":
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile.user)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():

            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
           
            messages.success(request, f'Acount Updated Successfully!')
            return redirect('profile', profile.user.username)
    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    
    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'userauths/profile_update.html', context)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out, what you need to is make sure to pass in `request.user` and also `request.user.profile` in the else: that shows that the forms is a GET request

**CODE SAMPLE**

```
def profile_update(request):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_form = form.save(commit=False)
            new_form.user = request.user
            new_form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Profile Updated Successfully.")
            return redirect("core:dashboard")
    else:
        form = ProfileForm(instance=profile)

    context = {
        "form": form,
        "profile": profile,
    }

    return render(request, "userauths/profile-edit.html", context)
```

Firstly Get the instance of whatever model you are trying to update, then in the line where you `request.POST` the data that would be passed into the input fields, also add instance=model_instance_you_are_trying_to_update in my case it was the profile so i did `instance=Profile`, let's say yours is a blog post then

1. Get the blog post

```
post = Posts.object.get(id=id)
postUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=post) # the instance=post would the existing fields
```

Comment: Any chance you could add your final code? Im having the same problem? (or did you updatae your post with your solution?)

Comment: I have updated my answer with the code that can help you achieve that